About software questions [Site FAQ] 
Let's decide our policy about these questions. After this has been decided I'll add the result to the FAQ.
The problem arose through the question Computer setup questions off topic. Please post your opinion or vote on others. When I see a strong enough tendency, that will be our policy. If you find this topic after it's been decided, feel free to post here or to post a new question about the topic (if the question deserves a question by itself).


Clear cases


Allow questions that ask for problems strictly related to Chinese. Take for example the question "Why can I not type 再见 (“goodbye”)?". This was closed but it's actually something we can solve, and not programming-related sites.
Forbid questions about how to write programs. They clearly don't belong here.



Ambiguous cases


Questions about terms that will be used in programs. This will depend on the question.

